# Usage of 'for' and 'have'

Tags: prepositions

Here is the situation. My birthday is coming. I feel fairly happy.

1. I am going to have a party for my birthday. Does 'for' here mean
   'because of' ?
2. I am going to have a party for my friends. Does 'for' here mean 'are
   intended or benefit from' ?
3. In the two statements above, does 'have' mean hold or organize?
   THank you. :)

Comment: Have you checked out [ell.se] yet? You might enjoy that site. (You're welcome to stay here, too, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

1. No. The [meaning of for](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/for?s=t) in that sentence is not "28. because of" nor is it a conjunction.  It's a combination of "10. with regard or respect to", "17. in honor of" and "25. as affecting the interests or circumstances of."
2. No. It's some combination of those numerous meanings again.
3. Yes.